# Executing SQL Script

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

when i run

```
SQL>execute deactivate_user
```

I get errors:

```
SQL> exec deactivate_user
BEGIN deactivate_user; END;

  *
```

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DEACTIVATE_USER'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Here is my code:

```
create or replace procedure deactivate_user 
(
p_username varchar2
)
as
l_username varchar2(30):=upper(p_username);
cnmd varchar2(50);
begin
    for rec in (select privilege, admin_option from dba_sys_privs
            where grantee =l_username) loop
            cnmd := 'REVOKE '||rec.privilege||' from '||l_username;
execute immediate cnmd;
end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create or replace procedure deactivate_user 
(
p_username varchar2
)
```

your procedure is expecting an input (there is no default, so theinput must be provided).

```
SQL> exec deactivate_user
```

You need to pass in the userid that you are trying to deactivate. Something like.

```
SQL> exec deactivate_user('USER1');
```

Comment: @user2062656 - You need to accept the answer - the one that you liked first, e.g. not mine. Always do this besides thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition:

```
create or replace procedure deactivate_user 
(
 p_username varchar2 DEFAULT 'USER1'
)
....
```

Then you do not need to enter the value for p_username. But by default your procedure will always be executed for 'USER1' unless you change the parameter as in Rajesh's example.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you need to pass the parameter while calling the store procedure as per your code.

as below:

```
exec deactivate_user('USERname1');
```

But if you dont want to pass any input value then set argument default parameter whenever you call sp then it will take automatic default value.

as below

```
create or replace procedure deactivate_user 
(
 p_username varchar2 DEFAULT 'USERname1'
)
```

....
Then you do not need to enter the value for p_username. But by default your procedure will always be executed for 'USERname1' unless you change the parameter value.

Then you will call the above procedure like:

```
exec deactivate_user;
```